# MVC3 Listbox Contents to Model Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, listbox

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and I was wondering if there's any way to create a listbox that contains the values which I would like my model to have.

Using @Html.ListBoxFor will only store the selected items into the model when the form is submitted rather than all the items in the listbox. I plan on using javascript to add items from another textbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not clear, but are you trying to POST values back?  If so, then they must be selected (i.e. active) form values in order to POST.  If you use JavaScript to add options to a listbox (HTML select> then these don't post.  You would need a multi-select enabled select and then flag each value you want to submit as selected.

To get values back they need to POST in some manner.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This has nothing to do with MVC3.  This is a limitation of the HTTP model.  When a form is posted, the browser only posts the selected value.  It does not post the other elements of the select list.

MVC must work within the framework of the way the browsers work, and this can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  You need a couple things to make this work though, it can be troubling.

In view:

```
//generate list box with 
<select id="NAMEOFLISTBOX" name="NAMEOFLISTBOX" multiple="multiple">
```

Okay, here is the part that most people miss.  The controller will only collect selected items if they are actually designated to be selected.  Therefore, where your submit button is you need to include some javascript.

```
<input type="submit" value="DO WORK" onclick="selectLISTBOXITEMS()" />
```

Script:

```
function selectLISTBOXITEMS(){
    var curList = document.getElementById("NAMEOFLISTBOX");
    for (var i = 0; i < curList.length; i++) {
        curList.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult controllerName(List<string> NAMEOFLISTBOX)
{
    foreach(string s in NAMEOFLISTBOX)
    {
        //do work
    }
    return RedirectToAction("controllerGet");
}
```

Not impossible, but the first time I did this it took a while to figure out why nothing was being sent.

Comment: Well, that's one way to do it, but it's extrely hackish.. It's much better to simply design your controller to get the values from the database instead, if you need them in the postback.  This would fall under the category of making me wince if I saw it in real code.

Comment: This is not for populating the listbox, it is for posting the values of the listbox to the controller.  He had said he wanted to manually populate the listbox with javascript, which is why I left the select tag open ended here.  Ideally you would pass in a typed model and then use the @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x...) to populate and bind the listbox where you had an IEnumerable<> in the model to hold the listbox values.

Comment: I still think it's hackish.  I would instead use a hidden field to store the fields, or i'd use Ajax to post the values to the controller as they were moved, keeping the model state in sync with the view.  Or i'd just post the values of the of the listbox to the controller via ajax prior to submitting.

Comment: I like your idea of using ajax to keep the listbox in sync, it is definitely a way to keep the page asynchronous - however, not all changes should be instantly committed to the database which is why a single post is nice for the user.  I was just trying to interpret what the OP had asked, and to be honest, it is a vague question.  Appending multiple hidden fields to the DOM also seems hackish, as does posting the listbox to a different controller than the post right before the post is called.